# Install Windows service on a remote machine using PowerShell 2.0

Tags: powershell

I want to use PowerShell 2.0 to install a Windows service after detecting if the service exists. I have the part to detect the service working but can't get the install to work.

```
$mc = [wmiclass]"\\"+"$ServiceServer\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_Service"
```

Running this line produces this error:

> Method invocation failed because [System.Management.ManagementClass] doesn't
>   contain a method named 'op_Addition'.

Comment: If I just hardcode the server name it seems to work. Any idea why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap all of the string in parentheses:

```
$mc = [wmiclass]("\\"+"$ServiceServer\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_Service")
```

The problem is that `[wmiclass]` is casting just the first string `"\\"` to  `[System.Management.ManagementClass]` which then is trying to add itself to a string.